# PHP issue after update to PHP 7-4 of Wordpress site

Tags: php, wordpress, button, upload, image-upload

I have updated the PHP version of my WordPress site from 7-0 to 7-4, and now I can no longer add media to posts or portfolio via the upload button "add image to slideshow".

Pls see screenshot attached.[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5GCva.jpg)

I've tried all PHP versions from 7-2 to 8-1 and deactivated all plugins with no success.

From Health check only 1 message pops up:

wordpress-importer.php
*Line 798 ERROR

Indirect access to variables, properties and methods will be evaluated strictly in left-to-right order since PHP 7.0. Use curly braces to remove ambiguity.*

The line content is: *$$meta['key'] = $meta['value'];*

Any idea or suggestion? Thanks

Comment: For that specific error, it appears you have a very old version of the [importer](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-importer/) you should upgrade that. For PHP, make sure you have all the required extensions.

Comment: thanks @Chris Haas, I have installed the wordpress importer app but nothing has changed. I assume the PHP extensions for 7-4 are installed on my apache server,  hosted by domainfactory, or is there anything I have to add manually? All pages and mysql looks all fine, only this stupid upload button not responding.

Comment: You should go and have a look into the actual PHP error log first of all.